# Can this be turned into a Case Switch?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to optimize my code and find any and all replications of code to minimize it and make it understandable to read... I'm still fairly new to `Case Switch` with VBA and I'm having a hard time trying to visualize this. Is the below code able to be turned into a `Case Switch` scenario?

```
If (optDelete.value) Then
    If (chkbxValid.value) Then
        Range("H4:I1000").ClearContents
    End If
    If (chkbxValidDuplicate.value) Then
        Range("K4:L1000").ClearContents
    End If
    If (chkbxInvalid.value) Then
        Range("N4:O1000").ClearContents
    End If
    If (chkbxInvalidDuplicate.value) Then
        Range("Q4:R1000").ClearContents
    End If
Else
    If (chkbxValid.value) Then
        Call SortData(Range("I4:I1000"), Range("H4:I1000"))
    End If
    If (chkbxValidDuplicate.value) Then
        Call SortData(Range("L4:L1000"), Range("K4:L1000"))
    End If
    If (chkbxInvalid.value) Then
        Call SortData(Range("O4:O1000"), Range("N4:O1000"))
    End If
    If (chkbxInvalidDuplicate.value) Then
        Call SortData(Range("R4:R1000"), Range("Q4:R1000"))
    End If
End If
```

This code uses check boxes with the following form, please see image below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
Select Case True
    Case optDelete.Value And chkbxValid.Value
        Range("H4:I1000").ClearContents

    Case optDelete.Value And chkbxValidDuplicate.Value
        Range("K4:L1000").ClearContents

    Case optDelete.Value And chkbxInvalid.Value
        Range("N4:O1000").ClearContents

    Case optDelete.Value And chkbxInvalidDuplicate.Value
        Range("Q4:R1000").ClearContents

    Case chkbxValid.Value
        Call SortData(Range("I4:I1000"), Range("H4:I1000"))

    Case chkbxValidDuplicate.Value
        Call SortData(Range("L4:L1000"), Range("K4:L1000"))

    Case chkbxInvalid.Value
        Call SortData(Range("O4:O1000"), Range("N4:O1000"))

    Case chkbxInvalidDuplicate.Value
        Call SortData(Range("R4:R1000"), Range("Q4:R1000"))

End Select
```

Based on your need, however, consider the cleanliness of:

Inside your main routine:

```
Call DeleteOrSortRoutine(optDelete.Value, chkbxValid.Value, Range("H4:I1000"), Range("I4:I1000"))
Call DeleteOrSortRoutine(optDelete.Value, chkbxValidDuplicate.Value, Range("K4:L1000"), Range("L4:L1000"))
Call DeleteOrSortRoutine(optDelete.Value, chkbxInvalid.Value, Range("N4:O1000"), Range("O4:O1000"))
Call DeleteOrSortRoutine(optDelete.Value, chkbxInvalidDuplicate.Value, Range("Q4:R1000"), Range("R4:R1000"))
```

And then, defined later in the module:

```
Private Sub DeleteOrSortRoutine(ByVal deleteCheck As Boolean, ByVal secondaryCheck As Boolean, ByVal range1 As Range, ByVal range2 As Range)
    If deleteCheck And secondaryCheck Then
        range1.ClearContents
    ElseIf secondaryCheck Then
        Call SortRange(range2, range1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't giving the output I was hoping for... Does my question make sense though? Maybe I need to rephrase it?

Comment: Ah, I see now that the logic you had was, effectively, a CASE statement with fall through rather than the VB/VBA Select Case which treats each case discretely. I think you will end up with some variation of your original IF..END IF structure since it sounds like you want multiple actions based on various checkbox values.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Is that possible?

Comment: I fear not because of the lack of fall-through. Unless you wanted to create Case statements that took into consideration EVERY possible checkbox/radio button combination. But that would create considerable amounts of repeated code not to mention the sheer volume of code would be untenable.

Comment: Alright, I didn't think so... Well thanks a lot for trying, I will leave this up here in-case some one else knows of a better way of attempting to optimize this.

Comment: While it doesn't incorporate the CASE statement, I have offered an alternative solution which makes things a bit cleaner and should make future enhancements (i.e. more checkboxes) easier to implement.

Comment: Tested and working for the second part of your answer! I love this method a lot more, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157587/discussion-between-forty3-and-maldred).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this chunk of code?

```
Select Case optDelete.Value
    Case chkbxValid.Value: Range("H4:I1000").ClearContents
    Case chkbxValidDuplicate.Value: Range("K4:L1000").ClearContents
    Case chkbxInvalid.Value: Range("N4:O1000").ClearContents
    Case chkbxInvalidDuplicate.Value: Range("Q4:R1000").ClearContents
End Select
Select Case optSort.Value
    Case chkbxValid.Value: Call SortData(Range("I4:I1000"), Range("H4:I1000"))
    Case chkbxValidDuplicate.Value: Call SortData(Range("L4:L1000"), Range("K4:L1000"))
    Case chkbxInvalid.Value: Call SortData(Range("O4:O1000"), Range("N4:O1000"))
    Case chkbxInvalidDuplicate.Value: Call SortData(Range("R4:R1000"), Range("Q4:R1000"))
End Select
```

Comment: Dani - that will compare the values in each Case statement against the `optDelete.Value` and if the two match, then it will execute the code. Therefore, if the `optDelete.Value` is `FALSE` and `chkbxValid.Value` is `FALSE` then it will run the `Range("H4:I1000").ClearContents` which, I suspect, is not what OP would want.